# 4 digit hex NSString to binary

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, binary, hex

I have an 4 digit Hex NSString that's something like "00C0" or "01C3". I would like to be able to convert this to binary to see what bits are toggled. My searches return too many irrelevant results, please help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[NSScanner](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html) should do the trick:

```
NSString *string1 = @"00C0";
NSScanner *scanner = [NSScanner scannerWithString:string1];
unsigned int number = 0;
if ([scanner scanHexInt:&number]) {
    NSLog(@"number is %u", number); // number is 192
}
```